# Adding map and/or reject to a reduce in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, view

I am calculating an ROI value that averages over a category.

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>       

  <h3><strong><%= category.name %><strong></h3>
  <% @category_products = category.products_by_warehouse_id(params[:id]) %>

    <!-- add map/reject below -->
    <%@ROI = (@category_products.reduce(0.0) {|acc, item| acc + (item.heritable_sale_price.to_f  * item.product_selections.length) / item.purchase_price.to_f }) %>

    <p> Category ROI: <%= number_with_precision((@ROI / @category_products.length.to_f), precision:2) %></p>

.....(close tags)......
```

The value throws `NaN` when financial data is missing. For individual values, this is fine; however, it does the same for averages with missing data as well.

How can I add `map`/`reject` into my call to throw out `nil` values, and get the average of what's available?

`@category_products.length.to_f` would also have to skip over empty elements in the array if I go this route as well, to keep the sum and length consistent. Something like `.where(purchase_price: [!nil, ""]).size` may work.

Comment: You can try using where.not to query your category_products: `where.not(heritable_sale_price: nil, product_selections: nil, purchase_price: nil)`. If that doesn't fix your problem, any second method called within the reduce block on the item variable is able to throw a NoMethodError.

Comment: If I take :purchase_price alone (:product_selections is a joined class, and sale price is a method) this works, and set up a second instance of <% `@category_products_count = category.products_by_warehouse_id(params[:id]).where.not(purchase_price: nil).size%>` in order to have consistent values for averaging. Submit as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in order to make sure, that none of the methods being accessed within the reduce block, to the item object are going to return nil, which hence, would throw a NoMethodError, you could firstly check them at the moment of creating your query. A `where.not` would do that. But keeping in mind that it'll leave aside each record in the database which doesn't satisfy the query criteria.

For that, then:

```
where.not(
  heritable_sale_price: nil,
  product_selections: nil,
  purchase_price: nil
)
```

For that, you can analyze the option on setting a default value for each of those columns, so this helps you avoiding the previous query, and having to rescue on each case where there's no value for them. You can see the [Rails Migration docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html).